# How to tell if a WinForms control's property is the "default" value?

Tags: winforms, properties, controls

How can i tell if a *property* of a WinForms `Control` is the "default" value?

**Note**: At design-time you can tell that a property no longer is the "default" when it becomes **bolded**.

> Here is an example (at design-time) of a label's font that is the
>   "default" value (which means it gets its value from its parent):
>
> [image]
>
> (and if the parent font changes, this label's font changes)
>
> Here a label's font has been changed, is no longer the default value:
>
> [image]
>
> (if the parent font changes, this label's font doesn't change)
>
> A careful observer will note that these two labels on the same panel are the "*same font*"; except one is **default** and the other *isn't*.

**Note**: i need to know at *runtime* if a property is not the "default" value. (Someone might cheat and say, "*Look at the properties window. If the property is bold you know it is no longer the default*".)

**Note**: Note, my question is not limited to fonts of labels - that's just the example i used. Examples of other properties that i might want to know if it's still default:

- `ForeColor`
- `BackColor`
- `ToolStrip.ImageScalingSize`
- `SplitContainer.FixedPanel`

---

**My descent into madness attempts**

i'll just leave these failed random rambling code vomit attempts here:

```
internal static Boolean GetIsPropertyDefault(object o, string propertyName)
{
    return false;

/*  Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("GetIsPropertyDefault: {0}.{1} = {2}", o, propertyName, TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(o)[propertyName].GetValue(o)));

    // Gets the attributes for the property.
    AttributeCollection attributes = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(o)[propertyName].Attributes;

    DefaultValueAttribute myAttribute = (DefaultValueAttribute)attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("The default value is: {0}", myAttribute));

    if (myAttribute == null)
        return true;

    return (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(o)[propertyName].GetValue(o) == myAttribute.Value);
*/

//          return (myAttribute.Value == null);



//          Console.WriteLine("The default value is: " + myAttribute.Value.ToString());

/*  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi;
    try
    {           
        //pi = o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultAttribute), false).
    }
    catch
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (pi == null) 
        return true;

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(pi.Attributes.ToString());
    */

//          return false;
/*          foreach (Attribute attr in pi.Attributes)
    {
        if (attr is System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute)
        {
            System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute dv = (System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute)attr;

        }
    }
*/
}
```

Comment: have a look at this similar Q - it has some good ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271904/can-you-detect-if-a-c-sharp-field-has-been-assigned-a-default-value. I was looking into DefaultValueAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx

Answer (score 4):

With reflection, you can examine the attributes for the `DefaultValue` attribute.  The PropertyGrid uses this to determine what should be bold and what shouldn't.

The "other" attribute to look for would be the `AmbientValueAttribute`.

When I did this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
Attribute[] attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Label).GetProperty("Font"));
foreach (Attribute att in attrs) {
  list.Add(att.ToString());
}
```

I got the following attributes:

- System.ComponentModel.AmbientValueAttribute
- System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispIdAttribute
- System.Windows.Forms.SRCategoryAttribute
- System.ComponentModel.LocalizableAttribute
- System.Windows.Forms.SRDescriptionAttribute

From [AmbientValueAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ambientvalueattribute.aspx):

> If a property on a control has ambient behavior, this attribute must be present. Ambient properties query their parent for their value, for example, a Control.Font property or a Control.BackColor property.
>
> Typically, a visual designer uses the AmbientValueAttribute attribute to decide which value to persist for a property. This is usually a value that causes the property to get its value from another source. An example of an ambient value is Color.Empty as the ambient value for the BackColor property. If you have a control on a form and the BackColor property of the control is set to a different color than the BackColor property of the form, you can reset the BackColor property of the control to that of the form by setting the BackColor of the control to Color.Empty.

Probably doesn't make what you are trying to do any easier, since the AmbientValue basically tells the class to look at it's parent.  For properties like "Font", you can just call the static function DefaultFont:

```
MessageBox.Show(Label.DefaultFont.ToString());
```

Which on my system, results in:

> [Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=8.25, Units=3, GdiCharSet=0, GdiVerticalFont=False]

Comment: `label1.GetType().GetProperty("Font").Attributes` contains `None`. Perhaps some code to explain how you would accomplish it.

Comment: There's another mechanism, a class can contain a ShouldSerializeXxxx() method where Xxxx is the property name.  Which is what is being used for the Font property.  Reflection required, it is an internal method.  The simple and obvious way is to just compare the property value with the parent's.

Comment: @HansPassant It can't be too internal, if the properties window is able to figure out if a control's property is no longer "what it should be"

Comment: PropertyGrid uses reflection.  Reflection can access internal and private members.

Comment: The ambient property might tell someone that they can look to the parent (and that may be the mechanism used, and not "default" values). But i wouldn't have to (in the case of Label.Font) use `Label.DefaultFont`, because i can just query `Label.Font`. But the question still remains, how do i know if `Label.Font` is the "non-bolded value"

Comment: @HansPassant Then i just need to know what the property grid does

Comment: It calls the object's ShouldSerializeFont() as I noted before.

Comment: @HansPassant What does it do for properties that aren't fonts?