# How do i get the default value of a control's font?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

i am trying to get the default value of a control's font so i can determine if it is currently the default value.

How do i get the default value of a control's font?

---

i **tried** getting the `DefaultValue` attribute of the `Font` property through reflection:

```
// Gets the attributes for the property.
AttributeCollection attributes = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(label1)["ForeColor"].Attributes;

//Find the "DefaultValue" attribute
DefaultValueAttribute myAttribute = (DefaultValueAttribute)attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];
```

except there is no default value attribute (`myAttribute` is null)

---

i then realized that there's the `AmbientValue` attribute, which means that the value of an attribute comes from a control's parent.

Following a control up it's `control.Parent` chain finds each of them have an `AmbientValue` attribute tag, all the way up to `Form`.

- label1 `[AmbientValue]` (no DefaultValue)

  - form1 `[AmbientValue]` (no DefaultValue)

    - `null`

So how do i get the default value of a control's `Font` property?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultfont(v=VS.100).aspx ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a WinForms control's property is the "default" value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251732/how-to-tell-if-a-winforms-controls-property-is-the-default-value)

Comment: @LarsTech That question deals with *any* property. This question deals with *just* `Font`. What's more, any techniques from that question don't appear to work for `Font`. Also, that question was a pipe dream (*How to tell if a property is at it's default value?* - there doesn't seem to be a way). It appears a more reasonable approach is to ask a separate question for each **type** of property.

Comment: @LarsTech i guess, technically, Charles answered my question. i asked "How to get a control's default font?". What i meant was, "How can i get if a control's Font is different than a control's default font?" i seem to be running in circles; when really i want to know "how to detect if a font is bold, but not **Bold**, but bolded in the properties window?"  Kill me.

Comment: I can hurt you more.  Take a label control, place it on a form, change it to bold, it gets bold in the PropertyGrid, change it back to regular, and it's "still" bold in the PropertyGrid.

Comment: @LarsTech Yeah, i have that case in my "other" question. Still, Microsoft solved it in Visual Studio (if only VS were open-source - or someone knew the answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about WinForms, I figure the [Control.DefaultFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultfont.aspx) property should help.

Comment: That doesn't work, because the font can still be "default", but not `Control.DefaultFont` (i.e. change the font of the form to "Comic Sans MS". A label on the form will then be "Comic Sans MS", but still the "default")

Comment: @IanBoyd That's the AmbientValue polling the parent for what should be its "default" font.  It's just a serialization issue.  Look in the designer file — the Form's font will be "Comic Sans MS" but the Label won't have any font property listed.

Comment: @LarsTech But i still can't figure out how to figure it out at runtime. i would think, internally, the font must be "`null`", meaning (get it from the parent). But when i read the property i won't see `null`.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that by 'default font' you mean the directly assigned font, not the inherited ambient font.

In the Control class, there is an internal method called IsFontSet.  It will return false if the Font is null.

```
bool? IsFontSet = null;

try {
    Type t = typeof(Control);
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("IsFontSet", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (mi != null) {
        IsFontSet = (bool?) mi.Invoke(view, null);
    }
} catch {}
```

A nullable bool was used so that it's value will be null if the method name is changed.  A try-catch is used so that if the return type is changed from bool to something else the code won't crash.